# Alias for Javascript import in VS Code: differentiate between local and remote

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In VS Code I open a file (in a larger project) where the first line of the file is an import like:
`const Invoice = require("/opt/nodejs/lib/invoice");`

In this case, locally, the file is stored under `./amplify/backend/function/myFunction/src/hander.js`

However, the `/opt/...`  directory is something that only exists remotely.
Locally the `/opt/..` directory is located under `./amplify/backend/function/myLayer/opt`

So, VS Code cannot resolve the  import.
This means I cannot click on the import (eg. "go to implementation" or just ctrl click").

How can I make sure VS Code knows where to find the file locally. But my import stays as is when the code is deployed?

I am looking for a way to tell VS Code that it should resolve "/opt/.." to "./amplify/backend/function/myLayer/opt/".
How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use an absolute path? Use `node_modules` normally, and possibly instruct your remote system to find global installs in `/opt/nodejs`. Do only `require('lib/invoice')`.

Comment: It's AWS lambda specific.
Imports from a layer need to come from `/opt/...` .
Or you can directly import in the lambda functions from `fileNameInTheLayer.js`.
But then it doesn't match the Amplify framework project structure and it still won't resolve locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) field of your [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) (or tsconfig.json) file.

Ex.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "/opt/*": ["./amplify/backend/function/myLayer/opt/*", "/opt/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

In the above list, the `"/opt/*"` in the JSON array (second element) is a fallback to the normal path mapping.